# Missing NIC in CentOS 5 - AsteriskNow 1.7.1

Tags: centos, kernel, make, ethernet, asterisk

So I have two nics, but I can't get the second to load, here is the output from

```
lspci -vvv


04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Unknown device 0000
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 169
    Region 0: Memory at fb900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at e000 [size=32]
    Region 3: Memory at fb920000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
            Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
            Status: D0 PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [d0] Message Signalled Interrupts: 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable-
            Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint IRQ 0
            Device: Supported: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, ExtTag-
            Device: Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            Device: AtnBtn- AtnInd- PwrInd-
            Device: Errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            Device: RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            Device: MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
            Link: Supported Speed 2.5Gb/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Port 0
            Link: Latency L0s <128ns, L1 <64us
            Link: ASPM Disabled RCB 64 bytes CommClk+ ExtSynch-
            Link: Speed 2.5Gb/s, Width x1
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Mask- TabSize=5
            Vector table: BAR=3 offset=00000000
            PBA: BAR=3 offset=00002000
```

I found out to use Intels e1000e drivers but when I use make install, I get the following:

```
[root@lan3 src]# make install
Makefile:67: *** Kernel header files not in any of the expected locations.
Makefile:68: *** Install the appropriate kernel development package, e.g.
Makefile:69: *** kernel-devel, for building kernel modules and try again.  Stop.
[root@lan3 src]#


[root@lan3 src]# yum install kernel-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, kmod
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile                                                * addons: centos.mirror.nac.net
 * base: centos.chi.host-engine.com
 * extras: mirror.metrocast.net
 * updates: mirror.trouble-free.net
Setting up Install Process
Package kernel-devel-2.6.18-409.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@lan3 src]#
```

Changing OS's is not an Option, I realize its old, but its a standard Intel Gigabit Nic. Any help is appreciated!

UPDATES:

```
# uname -r
2.6.18-194.11.1.el5
```

ifconfig doesn't show the NIC at all.

Comment: Please display output of ifconfig command and lsmod commad output

Comment: What does `uname -r` say?

Comment: Updated with outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution!

Install [elrepo repository](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php). && install kernel independant e1000e drivers from elrepo && tell kernel to use new drivers && reboot.

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-5-5.el5.elrepo.noarch.rpm && yum install kmod-e1000e && sudo nano /etc/modprobe.conf && reboot
```

Replace

```
#alias eth0 e100e
alias eth0 kmod-e1000e
```